# Focus search field by default

Tags: feature-request, search, focus

Since there are no other commonly used text inputs on the main list of questions (ignore tags, anyone?), how about focusing on the search input by default?

The behaviour of the inline "search" label would have to change slightly, but it should be simple enough and it will save <s>most users</s>users with a mouse a click.

Comment: Just *tab* and you are there.

Comment: I sure hate users who scroll with their keyboards, don't you, Fresh?

Comment: Why the downvote? Whether tabbing or clicking: it's one unnecessary action. @Toronto: Yes, and I would have responded sooner but I had to *tab* to the *Add Comment* button.

Comment: I gave this a downvote because I don't agree with it. Votes on Meta are used to indicate agree/disagree - nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I agree this is a very stupid idea, if people would like to use search they would use google, they should ask questions and NOT search for answers like some noobs. We will find answers for them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I land on the SOFU homepage, one of the first things I do is hit the `SPACEBAR` to scroll the page. And if you're not a `space` scroller, then I bet there's a shitload of people who are `page up` and `page down` scrollers. This breaks that too. Oh, and the `end` and `home` keys won't work either.

If I was focussed on the search box, then I would be typing a space in the search box, and where'd be the point in that? I'd come here complaining that the SOFU family of sites breaks the expected behavour of **every other website on the intertron**.

Search engines are of course the exception to this rule. But SOFU is not a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why we can't have our cake and eat it too. Put the focus in the search field; scrolling keys like PgUp and PgDn could be trapped and made to do the right thing. Since a space makes no sense as the first character of a search, even the space bar can be handled this way.

Comment: Another option is to focus the search field on the first alphanumeric character typed.